# How do I center a dynamically-changing background image without CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I center a dynamic background image? Tried using divs and center tags but it just breaks the code. Prefer to not use CSS. I've looked at the other threads and using the code in the html and body doesn't work.
The code:

```js
 setInterval(change_background, 1000 * 60 * 1);

function change_background() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();
  console.log(n);
  if (n == 19 || n < 7) {
    document.body.className = "night";
  } else {
    document.body.className = "day";
  }
  console.log("test");
}

change_background();
```

```css
.day {
  background-image: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg");
}

.night {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg");
}
```

```html
<body class="day" class="night"></body>
```

Comment: why not use CSS? CSS is intended for those tasks, use CSS flex to center elements.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Comment: What do you mean by “tried using divs and center tags”? And “it just breaks the code”? And why do you prefer not using CSS? Please be more specific.

Comment: The center tag is deprecated - you really should use CSS rather than use that to future-proof your code a bit better (browsers may stop implementing the center tag at some point). Perhaps if you could describe why CSS is something you want to avoid we could help you more - but TBH you need to use CSS nowadays to separaate out content from styling.

Comment: That question was approaching things from the wrong angle, sorry. I managed to edit the code such that the background image is centered but the question I should be asking is how can I make an image change according to the time of day using a centred img. I can't figure out how to change from background to normal image and still have the js work

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about what you are doing exactly?

my guess is that you try to make a dark mode or smoothing like that with the background changing and you want it to be depending on the time.

but the code is not clear, to be honest, and you need to organize it more with HTML and CSS, it will be much easier if you use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you want but this centers the pictures. Also
I changed the logic here: if (n >= 19 || n < 7) {

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .day {
            background-image: url(day.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .night {
            background-image: url(night.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="day" class="night">
    <script>
        setInterval(change_background, 1000 * 60 * 1)

        function change_background() {
            var d = new Date()
            var n = d.getHours()
            console.log(n)
            if (n >= 19 || n < 7) {
                document.body.className = 'night'
            } else {
                document.body.className = 'day'
            }
            console.log(document.body.className)
        }

        change_background()
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it in CSS, but if you want to use JS then you can do it with `document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center"`.

Try this between the script tags at the end of the body:

```
let hour
document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center"

setInterval(change_background, 1000 * 60 * 1);

function change_background() {
  hour = new Date().getHours()

  if (hour > 19 || hour < 7) {
    document.body.className = "night"
  } else {
    document.body.className = "day"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand in what way this isn't using CSS (it isn't using a stylesheet but that's different).

Comment: Yes, true. Though I interpreted the question as “I don't want to write CSS to center the image”, not "I don't want to set CSS style attributes to DOM nodes".